# How to add onchange event to svg fill attribute or path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want an event that triggers when a svg inside some tag with `id="someId"` changes.

Here is my not working code:

```
$('#someId svg["fill"]').on("change", () => {
 console.log("svg has changed")
});
```

what is wrong with it?

---

I tried these, but they are not working too:

```
$('#someId svg').on("change", () => {
 console.log("svg has changed")
});
```

or

```
$('#someId svg path').on("change", () => {
 console.log("svg has changed")
});
```

Comment: change events only work on HTML <input>, <textarea> and <select> elements per https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: As @RobertLongson said you are choosing the wrong event for this targeted type. Following your logic, if a script is changing (updating) your svg, you better call your event handler inside that script. if it's a third party plugin, check if it provides a callback api to use when "changes" happen...

Comment: If you are using CSS animations to change the fill value you can use `animationend` (keyframes) or `transitionend` (transitions). If you are using SMIL animations you may try `endEvent`

Comment: This is possible with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) as you can observe changes in an element's subtree or childList. Can you post the rest of your code?